# Is there a better way rather than `source ~/.bashrc` after I edit my .bashrc?

Tags: bash

There is some line in my ~/.bashrc:

```sh
...
export PATH="/XXX/YYY/ZZZ:$PATH"
export PATH="/AA/BB:$PATH"
...
```

And maybe I edit it one day:

```sh
...
# export PATH="/XXX/YYY/ZZZ:$PATH"
# export PATH="/AA/BB:$PATH"
export PATH="/CC/DD:$PATH"         # new line
export PATH="/EE/FF:$PATH"         # new line
...
```

Usually I saw the tutorial just `source ~/.bashrc` to update it after editing.
But in my case, it'll lead to :

```sh
$ echo $PATH
/EE/FF:/CC/DD:/AA/BB:/XX/YY/ZZ:(Original PATH)
```

/AA/BB, /XX/YY/ZZ still in there.
It force me to close the session and open a new one.

So, is there a better way for update ~/.bashrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
# Only if DEFAULTPATH is empty copy PATH to DEFAULTPATH
DEFAULTPATH="${DEFAULTPATH:=$PATH}"

export PATH="/CC/DD:$DEFAULTPATH"
export PATH="/EE/FF:$PATH"
```

Comment: pretty way! Although that means I have to do the same thing to all appended variable, I can just use `source ~/.bashrc` at least.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's really a way to "undo" changes to PATH (or other properties of the session), but you can just directly set PATH at the command-line:

```sh
PATH=/EE/FF:/CC/DD:(Original PATH)
```

Alternatively, you can have your .bashrc set the complete value of PATH, rather than merely prepending to it. For example:

```sh
export PATH='/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin'
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/usr/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/CC/DD:$PATH"
PATH="/EE/FF:$PATH"
```